# C# Windows Forms - Pegar o ID de um Usuário Logado

Tags: c#, visual-studio

preciso pegar o ID de um usuário já logado na aplicação para criar um outro produto. Como faço isso ?

[image: Login do Usuário]

[image: Cadastro do produto]

Então, eu logo, e com o email e senha logada, quero descobrir o ID logado para quando eu cadastrar o carro, ele puxar esse ID e cadastrar.
Já tentei usar o Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
Environment.UserName e o
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
mas esses só pegam o nome da pessoa logada no windows, não no aplicativo.

Login

```
        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        empresa.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        empresa.Senha = txtSenha.Text;
        if(EmpresaDAO.BuscarEmpresaPorEmailESenha(empresa) != null)
        {
            empresa = EmpresaDAO.BuscarEmpresaPorEmailESenha(empresa);
            this.Close();
            MenuEmpresa menuEmpresa = new MenuEmpresa();
            menuEmpresa.ShowDialog();  
        }
```

Cadastro do Carro

```
          try
            {
                if (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated)
                {
                   empresa.Email = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                }
                carro.Empresa = EmpresaDAO.BuscarEmpresaPorEmail(empresa);
                carro.Nome = txtNome.Text;
                carro.Cambio = txtCambio.Text;
                carro.Cor = txtCor.Text;
                carro.Marca = txtMarca.Text;
                carro.Quilometragem = txtQuilometragem.Text;
                carro.Placa = txtPlaca.Text;
                carro.Portas = int.Parse(txtPorta.Text);
                carro.Ano = int.Parse(txtPorta.Text);
                carro.Preco = txtPreco.Text;
                CarroDAO.Incluir(carro);

                MessageBox.Show("O cadastro do carro: " + carro.Nome + " foi concluido com sucesso", "Cadastrado");
            }
```

Tentei fazer o máximo igual possível ao do asp.NET,  porque não entendi como vou fazer isso em C#.

ASP.NET

```
Usuario usu = new Usuario();
            ItemVenda itemv = new ItemVenda();
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                usu.Login = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            venda.Usuario = UsuarioDAO.BuscarUsuarioPorLogin(usu);
```

Comment: Apresente o contexto do seu problema, isso deve incluir o código-fonte que está tendo problemas e exatamente o que tentou fazer

Comment: Coloquei o código que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: @OsvaldoJunior esta a programar para web ou desktop?

Comment: @gato Desktop, mas eu já consegui arrumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acreditando que a página que tem que fazer o cadastro do carro é a `MenuEmpresa` passe o login do usuário que é a variável `empresa` por parâmetro no momento de construir o objeto `MenuEmpresa`:

No trecho do login:

```
Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
empresa.Email = txtEmail.Text;
empresa.Senha = txtSenha.Text;
if(EmpresaDAO.BuscarEmpresaPorEmailESenha(empresa) != null)
{
    empresa = EmpresaDAO.BuscarEmpresaPorEmailESenha(empresa);
    this.Close();
    MenuEmpresa menuEmpresa = new MenuEmpresa(empresa); // <<<<<<<<< AQUI
    menuEmpresa.ShowDialog();  
}
```

Mas o ideal seria trabalhar com algum tipo de sessão, vou deixar para os devs de C# completarem isso!

Ah! e lembre-se no construtor da classe `MinhaEmpresa` deve haver a declaração da variável `empresa`

Comment: Vlw manooo, consegui fazer desse jeito que você falou passando a variável por parâmetro na hora de construir o objeto.